# DB Health Check in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an API to do a deep health check of my service.

Other than just doing a `SomeTableWhichIsNeverEmpty.first == nil`, is there a better way to check if my DB is up and available?  Preferably, the solution would be sqlite3, postgres, and mysql compatible.

I'm on rails 3.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very robust check. You could have corrupted indexes, a trashed log file, or no disk space left on the database partition and you'd never know it. These are but a few things off the top, and there are dozens more.

Comment: You're absolutely correct that those other things could happen.  In my experience, >90% of db outages have shown the symptom of my application being unable to connect, in a deep and meaningful manner, to the database.

Comment: @JohnHinnegan, were you able to do solve this problem, if yes please post your answer and mark it as accepted, would me helpful to me as well as for the community.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/blythedunham/health_monitor

Answer (score 0):

11 years later, this post still sees some action so here's an update. I am now on Rails 7.

I create a dedicated table in the DB to which I can read and write to. Given that I wanted to make sure the db was writable, I didn't see any alternative. Since this is storing only timestamps, I felt the storage overhead was negligible. With an outside caller checking on regular intervals, it also gives a history of when we were available -- assuming the healthcheck service is operating normally, a gap in records would indicate a gap in availability.

```rb
class CreateDbStatusChecks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :db_status_checks do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then I create an empty model. My status check calls `create` and `last` in order to verify write and read access. Very simple.

```rb
  def check_read
    DBStatusCheck.last
  rescue
    false
  end

  def check_write
    DBStatusCheck.create
  rescue
    false
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/). They do a pretty awesome job of monitoring rails and db health. It'd be hard to write something to compete and I think it's free for 1 or 2 rails apps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar.  I'm not necessarily trying to compete.  I'm offering an api and I'd like to provide clients a way to get the status of our system programmatically.  
The DB is just one of n dependent services I'd like to be able to report the health of.

Comment: you have to provide our own health checks, newrelic won't do that for you